# libusb cannot deinitialize context

Tags: java, usb, libusb

I need some help with a `IllegalStateException` in Java.
I got a sourcecode that should read out Data from a USB Device.

That code is not finished yet, but I already got the following error report

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: default context is not initialized at org.usb4java.Libusb.exit(Native Method) at testnew.main(testnew.java:122)
```

Line 122 is  `LibUsb.exit(null)`

Code is below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.usb.UsbConfiguration;
import javax.usb.UsbDevice;
import javax.usb.UsbDeviceDescriptor;
import javax.usb.UsbDisconnectedException;
import javax.usb.UsbException;
import javax.usb.UsbHostManager;
import javax.usb.UsbHub;
import javax.usb.UsbInterface;
import javax.usb.UsbInterfacePolicy;
import javax.usb.UsbNotActiveException;
import javax.usb.event.UsbPipeDataEvent;
import javax.usb.event.UsbPipeErrorEvent;
import javax.usb.event.UsbPipeListener;

import org.usb4java.BufferUtils;
import org.usb4java.DeviceHandle;
import org.usb4java.LibUsb;
import org.usb4java.LibUsbException;

public class testnew {

private final static short VENDOR_ID = 0x0403;
private final static short PRODUCT_ID = 0x6001;
private static byte IN_ENDPOINT = (byte) 0x81;
private static long TIMEOUT = 5000;
private final static int INTERFACE = 0;
private final static Object CONNECT_HEADER = 000;
private final static Object CONNECT_BODY = 000;

public static UsbDevice getHygrometerDevice(UsbHub hub) {
    UsbDevice launcher = null;

    for (Object object : hub.getAttachedUsbDevices()) {
        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) object;
        if (device.isUsbHub()) {
            launcher = getHygrometerDevice((UsbHub) device);
            if (launcher != null)
                return launcher;
        } else {
            UsbDeviceDescriptor desc = device.getUsbDeviceDescriptor();
            if (desc.idVendor() == VENDOR_ID && desc.idProduct() == PRODUCT_ID)
                return device;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static char readKey() {
    try {
        String line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
        if (line.length() > 0)
            return line.charAt(0);
        return 0;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read key", e);
    }
}

public static ByteBuffer read(DeviceHandle handle, int size) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.allocateByteBuffer(size).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    IntBuffer transferred = BufferUtils.allocateIntBuffer();
    int result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, IN_ENDPOINT, buffer, transferred, TIMEOUT);
    if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS) {
        throw new LibUsbException("Unable to read data", result);
    }
    System.out.println(transferred.get() + " bytes read from device");
    return buffer;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Search for the missile launcher USB device and stop when not found
    UsbDevice device;
    try {
        device = getHygrometerDevice(UsbHostManager.getUsbServices().getRootUsbHub());

        if (device == null) {
            System.err.println("Missile launcher not found.");
            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }

        // Claim the interface
        UsbConfiguration configuration = device.getUsbConfiguration((byte) 1);
        UsbInterface iface = configuration.getUsbInterface((byte) INTERFACE);

        iface.claim(new UsbInterfacePolicy() {
            @Override
            public boolean forceClaim(UsbInterface usbInterface) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        iface.getUsbEndpoint(IN_ENDPOINT).getUsbPipe().addUsbPipeListener(new UsbPipeListener() {

            @Override
            public void errorEventOccurred(UsbPipeErrorEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void dataEventOccurred(UsbPipeDataEvent arg0) {
                for (byte b : arg0.getData())
                    System.out.print(b);
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        });
        ;
    } catch (UsbNotActiveException | UsbDisconnectedException | UsbException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Deinitialize the libusb context
    LibUsb.exit(null);
}

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you did not initialize the context this is why you get the error when you try to deinitialize it, see http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.usb4javaLibUsb example 17

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  //Initialize the libusb context

int result = LibUsb.Init(null);
if (result != LibUsb.SUCCESS){
     throw new LibUsbException("Unable to initialze libusb",result);
}
[...]
```

how to open the pipe depends on what transfer type you want to choose (bulk transfer, sychronous transfer, asynchronous transfer), see http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html

for synchronous transfer you can use (copied from http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html)

```
UsbEndpoint endpoint = iface.getUsbEndpoint((byte) 0x83);
UsbPipe pipe = endpoint.getUsbPipe();
pipe.open();
try
{
    byte[] data = new byte[8];
    int received = pipe.syncSubmit(data);
    System.out.println(received + " bytes received");
}
finally
{
    pipe.close();
}
```

There are IN endpoints and OUT endpoints, you write to OUT and read from IN. Control transfers go to  EP0. All USB communication is initiated by the host device, meaning the USB device can not even initiate a communication.

for deeper information on USB protocol see http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml

Comment: Okay, got it. That was simple mistake..
How do i keep going on? I wanna read out the data from the pipe.. but first i have to open the pipe.. where? And how do i read out the data?